# Can't access an item in a dictionary that does in fact exist

Tags: python, html, django, forms, http

I have two buttons on my page, each one in its own separate form.

One of the buttons, "deleteImage", works perfectly fine.

The other button, "search", won't work.

This is my response.POST when search is pressed.

```
request.POST <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['randomtoken1234'], 'search': ['food', '']}>
```

request.POST.get("search") is failing to work for some reason, I tried printing it as well and nothing prints out.

my html

```
<form method="post" action="" class="form-group">
{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        {{form_search.search}}
        <div class="input-group-append">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="search">Search!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the QueryDict the key `search` is shown as `'search': ['food', '']`. This means there are two values posted for `search` where one is an empty string.

I assume that this is because other than your button the form field for the search input is **also** named `search`. When one writes `request.POST.get("search")` they get the *last* value for the given key which here is an empty string for you (the value of the button).

The solutions are:

1. Change the name of the form field from `search` to something else.
2. Change the name of the submit button from `search` to something else. Which will be something like:

   ```
    <form method="post" action="" class="form-group">
       {% csrf_token %}
       <div class="input-group mb-3">
           {{form_search.search}}
           <div class="input-group-append">
                <!-- Change name attribute of button -->
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="search-pressed">Search!</button>
           </div>
       </div>
    </form>
   ```

Note that you might need to make some changes in your view as well to reflect these changes in the name.

Comment: thank you this fixed my error. any reason why it takes the last value of the key? can I choose what value it can take?

Comment: @Wizard that is because `request.POST` is a `QueryDict` (a specialized type of dictionary where each key can have multiple values because in GET or POST requests can have the same key with multiple values (checkboxes, select multiple, etc.)) You can check the [documentation for QueryDict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding a value to the search button

```
<form method="post" action="" class="form-group">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <div class="input-group mb-3">
       {{form_search.search}}
       <div class="input-group-append">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="search" value="{{form_search.search}}">Search!</button>
       </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: this is a solution, but still not the one I wanted if anyone has something else to suggest